# Exit powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have this powershell script that trigger some instruction when a file is created in a certain directory.
All works well, but I'm not able to close the powershell after that the action is done.
How can I do that?

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\Autostrade\CartellaSFTP"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
$uscita = 0

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
            Add-content "C:\Users\Autostrade\PHP Script Dati Telepass\log.txt" -value $logline
            # Set up references to executable and script
            $PhpExe  = "C:\PHP\php.exe"
            $PhpFile = "C:\Users\Autostrade\PHP Script Dati Telepass\script.php"

            # Create arguments from Script location
            # usually php.exe is invoked from console like: 
            # php.exe -f "C:\path\myscript.php"
            #$PhpArgs = '-f "{0}"' -f $PhpFile

            # Invoke, using the call operator
            $PhpOutput = & $PhpExe $PhpFile
            PhpOutput
            $uscita = 1
          }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
#Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
#Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
#Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while (!$uscita) {sleep 5}
exit
```

I tried using that "$uscita" variable to stop the while and exit, but it's not working. I tried also to put at the end of the action the exit command, but that is not working too

Comment: `$uscita = 1` -> `$using:uscita = 1`

Comment: I tried.. The powershell give some errors and immediatly close.. I'm not able to read what is the error

Comment: Remove the `exit` and run the script from a PowerShell prompt.

Comment: It gives me this exception:
CategoryInfo: ParseError (:) [], ParseException
FullyQualifiedErrorId: InvalidLeftHandSide

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the complete error. Don't post a screenshot; copy/paste it as text.

Comment: Done. I found a solution, but I've another little question

Comment: When I asked you to edit your question I meant put the error message into your question, not put an answer or a followup question into your question. Answers should be posted as answers. Followup questions should be posted as new questions.

Comment: ok.. sorry.. I put my solution like new answer

Answer (score 3):

I edited the last part of my code in this way and now it works. So after the action, the script ends itself.
Here's the code:

```
while (!$uscita) {
if($? -eq $false) {
    exit
    }
sleep 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Offhand it looks like your 2nd to last line with the while is probably returning true, so it just sits in the sleep command.

Try this to test, it will return true if the last command completed successfully.

```
while (!$uscita) {write-output $?; sleep 5}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried. When I insert a file in he directory that I'm monitoring, it gives me "false".. But the loop dpesn't stop. It continues and returns true

Comment: That makes sense, we're getting closer. $? will tell you (true/false) if the previous command succeeded and it did. Now I'm wondering: you said "it give me 'false'", do you mean that the statement !$uscita returns $true? (meaning $uscita -eq $false).

Comment: I'm not sure the answer you posted is the best way to do it. Instead of setting $uscita = 1 consider setting $uscita = $true. Then to troubleshoot use - while (!$uscita) {write-output $uscita; sleep 5}. If this still loops infinitely it means that the $uscita = $true line isn't getting hit. Start putting other write-outputs in the $action block or higher up so that you can see where the issue is. Don't forget to troubleshoot the function PhpOutput. Unexpected behavior there could prevent $uscita from being set.